# If a quadratic form $Q:\ V\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ is non-vanishing except at $0$ then $Q$ is positive or negative definite

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

Let $Q:\ V\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ be a quadratic form such that $Q(u)\ne 0$ for all $u\ne0$. Then $Q$ is positive or negative definite.

From the definition, I need to show $Q(u)>0$ (or $<0)$ for any $u\ne0$. Given $u\ne0$, without loss of generality, assuming that $Q(u)>0$. But I have no idea how to start from this, what should I do next ? Thanks.

Comment: Assume, there are $u,v\in V$ with $Q(u) >0$ and $Q(v) <0$, then $f\colon [0, 1]\to \mathbb R,\ t\mapsto Q(tu+(1-t) v) $ is continuous and $f(0)<0<f(1) $. Can you continue from here. Observe $Q(u) =Q(-u) $, so $0_V$ is not on the line between $u$ and $v$ .

Comment: I wonder why $Q(u)=Q(-u)$ impies $0$ is not belong to the line segment $[u.v]$ ?

Comment: If we had $v=\lambda u$, then it would be $Q(v) =\lambda^2\cdot Q(u) >0$.

Comment: @Jochen I got it, many thanks for your helpful hint